# How to pass run arguments in app.yaml for Go?

Tags: go, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-go

According to [Docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#runtime_and_app_elements):

> **entrypoint**
> Optional. Overrides the default startup behavior by executing the entrypoint command when your app starts. For your app to receive HTTP requests, the entrypoint element should contain a command which starts a web server that listens on port 8080.

How would I configure this? there are no details found anywhere.
Can I do this?

```yaml
entrypoint: go run main.go fooArg --bar-flag=1
```

I don't have cloud build file, only app.yaml. so what does **entrypoint** really do?
when app engine reaches **entrypoint** part is the program already compiled?

Thank you

Comment: Can you post the content of your `app.yaml`?

Comment: my app.yaml has nothing special, just resource management

Comment: Sometimes `entrypoint` is ignored based on what you have `runtime` set to. For example, `entry point` is ignored for `runtime: custom`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this just now with my own GCP AppEngine project and using `entrypoint` (eg. `entrypoint: go run ./cmd/web prod`) did not work for me.  When I tried it, I am getting this cryptic error message:

```
Error type: UNKNOWN
Error message: no Go files in /layers/google.go.appengine_gomod/srv
```

I'm using `Google Cloud SDK 344.0.0`.

I'm in a similar situation like you though where I'm simply trying to pass in `args` into my golang main. Following [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#runtime_and_app_elements), I changed over to using `env_variables` instead which worked.

My app.yaml looks like:

```
runtime: go115
main: ./cmd/web
env_variables:
  APP_ENV: "prod"
```

and then in my code, I simply use `os.Getenv("APP_ENV")` anywhere to access.